# GeckoFX 22 How to get POST data in Navigating event

Tags: c#, events, post, geckofx

I am trying to get POST data from the page to which browser is about to navigate, do some processing and repost/redirect it.

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
//how get POST data ??
}

GeckoNavigatingEventArgs have no POST data property

 public class GeckoNavigatingEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
    {
        public readonly GeckoWindow DomWindow;
        public readonly bool DomWindowTopLevel;
        public readonly Uri Uri;

        public GeckoNavigatingEventArgs(Uri value, GeckoWindow domWind);
    }
```

I used in the past csEXWB control which has 'public object postdata;' in his BeforeNavigate2EventArgs

Unfortunately csEXWB is getting too old and is not an option to be used.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I found how

```
Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement element = (Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement)this.geckoBrowser.Document.GetHtmlElementById("amount");
            string amount = element.DefaultValue;
```